# SQL: What is a good way to combine data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql

Here's what I'm trying to achieve on generating a "Summary" page.

I want to join 6 tables together (1 "main" Table X, and 5 other tables containing certain reference to Table X). I only need a column or 2 from each of the 5 tables.

What is a good way to do this?

What I currently have in mind..

1. Join all 6 tables in SQL, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to go, as the query will be really long.
2. Do separately queries, and join them in the code.

Comment: How do you define a good way? Performance or length of query?

Comment: I can't imagine why you wouldn't join the tables in the query.  Database engines are really good at that sort of thing.

Comment: I prefer using JOIN than UNION

Comment: I'm trying to find out what is the usual way of doing it in this situation, as I'm still new to programming. I was thinking that joining 6 tables would make the query look messy and hard for others to understand.

Comment: @Charlesliam - JOIN and UNION are different things, producing different results.

Comment: Joining the tables in SQL is the right way to go. Doing your joins in code is not. If you're concerned about it being long and messy write a stored procedure, make the code tidy, and put comments in.

Comment: I see. Thanks @LeeWillis and everyone for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your data.
First of all, the query length doesn't matter. What matters is number of joins, size of tables, indexes, etc. All these affect the execution time.
There are some cases when it is better to perform separate queries.
You may have some data that you store in cache, so that you map it in code to the results after the query execution and receiving results. It can be useful when it is a small table like "types"

Answer (score -1):

Best way would be to use a stored procedure for this. Use the cursors, with each cursor getting the column values needed for the same.

This is how it would look

Procedure P1 has Cursors C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5

In Cursor C1, Use a view to get the required data using simple SQL.

Similarly do the same for all the cursors.

After all the cursors get the required value, use results of each cursor to populate each Column of your report/summary.

Comment: If you can query using a join on the key columns then a cursor is unnecessary.

Comment: Do you think cursors are better performance variant than JOINS?

Comment: I agree, performance can really be an issue while using cursors, but I have used it in similar situations with decent results. Anything that floats the boat!